# Invoke Lead Assignment Rule While Creating Lead Through Apex

Tags: apex, developer

How I can Invoke Lead Assignment Rule While Creating Lead Record through Apex, I tried below Code but seems it is not working.

```
Database.DMLOptions dmlOption = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlOption.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
Database.update(leadList, dmlOption);
```

Comment: and the debug log doesn't show assignment rules being run?